# Redux reducer throwing up intermittent error

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a react native app that I'm running in IOS simulator.  During initialization, it reads a Parse database and populates a redux datastore using the following reducer:

```
    export default function items( state = [], action ) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case types.ADD_ASSIGNMENT:

                return [
                    ...state, 
                    {
                        assignmentId: action.assignmentId,
                        shopperId: action.shopperId,
                        itemId: action.itemId,
                        createdAt: action.createdAt
                    }
                ];
             case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
                return [];

            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
```

When I run the app repeatedly, it is failing roughly 1 out of 3 times with the following redux-logger error:

```
action ADD_ASSIGNMENT @ 19:02:09.732
    prev state Object {router: Object, auth: Object, device: Object, global: Object, profile: Record…}
    action Object {type: "ADD_ASSIGNMENT", assignmentId: "oNncJdVT16", shopperId: "aoieAPH6ll", itemId: "gza3038iPN", createdAt: Tue Feb 09 2016 11:43:48 GMT-0500 (EST)}
    error TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemId' of null(…)
    next state Object {router: Object, auth: Object, device: Object, global: Object, profile: Record…}
        assignments: Array[1]
            0: Object
                assignmentId: "oNncJdVT16"
                createdAt: Tue Feb 09 2016 11:43:48 GMT-0500 (EST)
                itemId: "gza3038iPN"
                shopperId: "aoieAPH6ll"
```

Notice how the error states that itemId is null, but the action actually includes a non-null itemId.  The next state appears to be correct, but the app doesn't recover after it encounters this error (unfortunately, it doesn't throw up a red-screen with additional information).

I've also captured the identical redux-logger event showing the same action without any error:

```
action ADD_ASSIGNMENT @ 19:01:50.601
    prev state Object {router: Object, auth: Object, device: Object, global: Object, profile: Record…}
    action Object {type: "ADD_ASSIGNMENT", assignmentId: "oNncJdVT16", shopperId: "aoieAPH6ll", itemId: "gza3038iPN", createdAt: Tue Feb 09 2016 11:43:48 GMT-0500 (EST)}
    next state Object {router: Object, auth: Object, device: Object, global: Object, profile: Record…}
        assignments: Array[1]
            0: Object
                assignmentId: "oNncJdVT16"
                createdAt: Tue Feb 09 2016 11:43:48 GMT-0500 (EST)
                itemId: "gza3038iPN"
                shopperId: "aoieAPH6ll"
```

Any suggestions on how to procced?

Comment: It's not saying itemId is null. It's saying it can't access the itemId property of a null object. Is there anywhere else in your code where you're trying to access the `itemId` property?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out.  I misnamed the Redux "assignments" reducer function as "items" (as shown in my previous code snippets).

The reason why it was exhibiting intermittent behavior is because there are two possible code execution paths:

1) If the code execution processes an "ADD_ITEM" action, then the "item" reducer properly initializes the "items" data structure in the redux datastore.

2) However, if "ADD_PROPOSAL" executes first, then the "items" data structure is not properly initialized thus causing the error.